# How to use proxy api with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web, web-scraping, puppeteer, chromium

I built a web scraper for ab white using puppeteer, i connected to a proxy server scraper api using the code below

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        args: [
            `--proxy-server=http://${PROXY_SERVER}:${PROXY_SERVER_PORT}`
        ]
    });
```

I am also to authenticate the page as shown below.

```
await page.authenticate({
        username: PROXY_USERNAME,
        password: PROXY_PASSWORD,
      });
```

Whenever I run my code without proxy, everything goes fine but my session gets blocked after many quick requests. Hence the scraper doesn't finish, but if I run it with the scraper it gets very slow , like it keeps spinning for 15 minutes, or it returns not secure error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: have you checked your proxy to see if it's working  ? just type the proxy address in your browser and see if it opens